# The chance to double 1000 points into 2000 points

Tags: probability

You own 1000 points.

Your goal is to reach 2000 points, the only way you gain points is by gambling.

You will always gamble 40 points, your chance of winning a 40 points gamble is 60%, how high is your chance to double your points?

I'm pretty sure the solution is pretty simple, but I'm breaking my head over this, god I feel stupid I'm asking for help online, if some-one can help me with this problem it'd be much appreciated!

EDIT: You loose if you reach 0 points! Something important I forgot to add before, I think most people understood it though.

Comment: In your question the number of gambles is not limited. The quickest way is to win 50 times in a row, the next runs with 51 wins and one loss. Etc. If one gets a total probability for $N$ runs, i do not if that would converge for infinite $N$.

Comment: I know, but there's no way to calculate it? :o

Comment: @mvw actually it kind of is (sort of). If the amount of gambles lost exceeds the amount of gables won by 25 then you have lost all your money. If the amount of gambles won exceeds the amount of gables lost by 25, you've doubled the money.

Comment: You are right, 25 is the right number, not 50. sorry.

Comment: One could also interpret it as a 1 dim random walk, where one wants to know if the walker will make another 1000  meters. I guess is he always will, if one waits long enough, thanks to the 60% bias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic [Gambler's Ruin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) problem. For information, please see the Wikipedia article, and then some of its references.

First note that equivalently we may assume the player starts off with $25$ dollars and makes $1$ dollar bets, and wants to reach $50$ dollars.

We can imagine the game as involving **two** gamblers, each starting with $25$ dollars. Gambler A has probability $p$ of winning a bet, and Gambler B has probability $q=1-p$ of winning any bet, where $p\ne q$.  Results of successive bets are independent. In your case, $p=0.6$ and $q=0.4$.

Suppose  Gambler A starts with capital $n_1$, and Gambler B starts with $n_2$. In our case $n_1=n_2=25$.  Then the probability that A reaches her goal of ending up with all of the $n_1+n_2$ before going broke is 
$$\frac{1-(q/p)^{n_1}}{1-(q/p)^{n_1+n_2}}.$$
The proof is not easy.

**Remark:** In the case $p=q=1/2$, the above formula cannot be used. The probability A reaches her goal before going broke is $\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$.

Comment: Thanks! Your formula makes me feel a lot less stupid, no wonder I couldn't come to an answer ha, this world is blessed with your mind. lol :D I'll try to fill in the formula and type my result in this chat later!

Comment: Is there any interaction between player A and B? Why a second player?

Comment: We can imagine the "house" as being B, as soon as the house is ruined, player A has her 50 dollars.

Comment: Every time I try to fill in the formula with your logic I get a negative answer, that doesn't make sense right? It has to be between 0 and 1

Comment: What I wrote was unclear to wrong. For our case we have $q/p=2/3$. The probability that A reaches $50$ (and goes home) before losing her $25$ dollars is $\frac{1-(2/3)^{25}}{1-(2/3)^{50}}$. A scientific calculator should have no trouble with that. One can in this case do some preliminary algebra and get $\frac{1}{1+(2/3)^{25}}$. The result is very close to $1$, about $0.99996$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's supose you have an infinite amount of points so no matter how many times you lose, you can still play.

You want to win 1000 points in 40 points gambles. So after a certain amount of gambles, the amount of gambles won, $w$ must exceed by 25 the amount of gambles lost, $l$:

$w - l = 25$.

So in $w + l$ plays, you lose $l$ times: there are ${w+l\choose l} = {25 + 2l\choose l}$ ways to do that. Each with a chance of $(1/6^{25+l})(1/4^l)$ to happen:

The chance to double your money is:

$$W = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {25+2k \choose k}\frac{1}{6^{25+k}}\frac{1}{4^k} = \frac{1}{6^{25}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {25+2k \choose k}\frac{1}{24^k} $$

But we don't have an infinite amount of money. If at some point $l = w + 26$ then we can't continue playing.

So we must substract the chance of that happening.

This time, we play $l + w$ times, i.e. $2w + 26$ and we win $w$ times. There are $2w + 26 \choose w$ ways for that to happen, each with a chance of $(1/6^w)(1/4^{26+w})$ to happen.

So the chance to lose all our money before we win is:

$$L = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {26+2k \choose k}\frac{1}{6^k}\frac{1}{4^{26+k}} = \frac{1}{4^{26}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {26+2k \choose k}\frac{1}{24^k} $$

The chance to double your money is thus $W - L$.

Answer (score 0):

How can you figure out the probability for yourself (doing a calculation, and not a formula): You start with 25 coins. You bet until you have either 0 coins or 50 coins. When you have n coins and bet, you end up with n-1 coins with probability 0.4, and with n+1 coins with probability 0.6. We call it "winning" if you end up with 50 coins. Let p (k) be the probability that you end up winning if you start with k coins, for 0 <= 0 <= 50.

Clearly $p (0) = 0$.

If you have one coin, you will bet it and end up with 0 or 2 coins with different probabilities. So $p (1) = 0.4 p (0) + 0.6 p (2) = 0.6 p (2)$.

If you have two coins, you will bet one coin and end up with 1 or 3 coins. So $p (2) = 0.4 p (1) + 0.6 p (3) = 0.24 p (2) + 0.6 p (3)$. This makes $0.76 p (2) = 0.6 p (3)$, and $p (2) = (0.6 / 0.76) p (3)$.

You repeat the same calculation for k = 3, k = 4, ..., k = 49, and each time you find that p (k) = some constant * p (k + 1). Finally, p (50) = 1. This allows you to calculate in turn p (49), p (48) and so on.